# How Can I Stop the 360 in Boot Complete?

Tags: android

When I install the 360, I find this app will start when the boot completes.  How can I stop this?
 I use the following code:

```
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(component,
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But this also starts when the boot completes!

Can anyone help?

Comment: 360自己那个设置后，重启还是有360的进程，我就不想让360启动，任何进程都不要

Answer (score 2):

At end of your code Your code write this.

```
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
```

Try. And Reply.

Comment: in place of **receiver** write **component**